# A,B,C are events such that A and C are independent. How do I prove that A intersection B is also independent with C?

Tags: probability

A,B,C are events such that A and C are independent. How do I prove that A intersection B is also independent with C ?

Comment: You can't.  Suppose $B=C$, for instance.